# $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ axis and angle representation

Tags: group-theory

I have a question about the rotation matrix of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$,

$$\exp\left(-\mathrm{i}\vec\theta\cdot\vec\sigma/2\right)$$

in this form, it represents a rotation at the angle $\theta$ around the axis $\hat{n}=\vec{\theta}/\lvert{\vec{\theta}\rvert}$. How do you show that $\hat{n}$ and $\theta$ indeed mean geometrically the axis and the angle of the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that $\hat n$ points in the direction $(\theta,\phi)$, i.e.
$$\hat n_z=\cos\theta,\quad\hat n_x=\sin\theta\cos\phi,\quad \hat n_y=\sin\theta\sin\phi$$
Then one demands that the states $|\hat n,\pm\rangle$ are eigenvectors of $\hat n\cdot\vec S$. You can think of this dot product as the projection of the spin operator $\vec S$ along the axis of rotation $\hat n$. I think this clears up $\hat n$. One checks that $\theta$ has the correct interpretation by considering a rotation about, for instance, the $z$-axis. Then the rotation operator has the form $\exp(-\mathrm{i}\theta\sigma_z/2)$. Suppose we rotate the coordinate system so that the old $z$-axis is now $\hat n$. Then $\sigma_z\rightarrow \hat n\cdot\vec\sigma$ as explained earlier. The parameter $\theta$ is obviously unaffected. Thus the rotation operator is $\exp(-\mathrm{i}\vec\theta\cdot\vec\sigma/2)$.