# How to write a matrix from $SU(2)$ in terms of one angle and one complex number $z$ , where $z$ is from sphere $S^{2}$

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, parametrization, mobius-transformation

For given a matrix from $SU(2)$ , how can represent it in terms of two parameters: one angle and one complex number $z$ from the sphere $S^{2}$ ?
Does this have any links with : [$\mathrm{SU}(2)$ axis and angle representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216980/mathrmsu2-axis-and-angle-representation) ?
Can someone help me do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is “one complex number from the sphere $S^2$”? The elements of that sphere are *not* complex numbers.

Comment: in my exercise is written so,it can be that  it is a mistake...What if I don't have that z is complex,hence any z of sphere $S^{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is of the form 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
a & -\overline{b}\\
b & \overline{a}
\end{matrix}
\right), \qquad \lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2 = 1, \quad a,b \in \mathbb C.
$$
Write $a=x+yi, b=z+wi$. Note that the equation $\lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2 = 1$ says that $$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1,$$ which is the equation of a three-sphere $\mathbb S^3$ in $\mathbb R^4$. Identify $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the space of quaternions $\mathbb H$, so that $(x,y,z,w)$ corresponds to $x+yi+zj+wij \in \mathbb H$ (this is only a correspondence of vector spaces). Now, since $i,j,ij$ span an $\mathbb R^3$ in $\mathbb H$, define $u$ as a unit vector in their span which is proportional to $yi+zj+wij$, so that $u \in \mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$ (there are two choices for this vector). You can write the quaternion $x+yi+zj+wij$ as $$\cos \vartheta 1+ \sin \vartheta u, \qquad \text{ for some } \vartheta \in \mathbb S^1.$$ Obviously $x^2 = \cos^2 \vartheta$ and $y^2+z^2+w^2=\sin^2 \vartheta$. Therefore, $(\vartheta,u) \in \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^2$ is one of the possible pairs you are looking for.

Comment: What does the $1$ near the cosine stand for?

Comment: For the number $1$. I am looking at $\mathbb H$ as the span of $1,i,j,ij$.

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216980/mathrmsu2-axis-and-angle-representation has any links with you result?

Comment: Probably yes, but there are some things in the language they use I do not understand.

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: $\vartheta$
 is an angle? I need a parametrisation with an angle...

Comment: It is an angle, yes. I write $\vartheta \in \mathbb S^1$ as a shorthand.

Comment: Nice,thanks a lot one more time:)